# Going back to submitted form in Firefox 10: Not-cached / expired warning

Tags: forms, firefox

When I submit a form in Firefox 10.0.1 (e.g. editing an article on Wikipedia) and go back via the back button, I get a warning that the form is expired or not cached.

How can I disable that to behave like before (load filled form again)?

German error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WrRf.png

> Dokument erloschen
>
> Dieses Dokument ist nicht mehr verfügbar.
>
> Das angefragte Dokument ist nicht im Browser-Cache verfügbar.Als Sicherheitsmaßnahme fragt der Browser um vertrauliche Dokumente nicht automatisch erneut an.Klicken Sie "Nochmal versuchen", um das Dokument erneut von der Website anzufragen.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem: the unsaved content of the form is lost when I get this warning. This was not the case with older Firefox versions (there I got a different warning and I could get back to my un-saved content)

[At Mozillazine](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2397107) someone suggest that the website should add the header `Cache-Control: max-age=600` to prevent this. Don't know if that's advisable or if it works.

Same [at this thread at PHP Freaks](http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=354333.0).

Answer (score 1):

As proposed by the guy from the mozillazine.org forum, I have tried the max-age setting within the cache-control, and it works indeed. However, it is up to the website developers to make this work, and it depends on the form if enabling the cache-control makes sense. Personally, I would turn this behaviour off within the Firefox configuration if I knew how to do this.